# How to extract text from coordinates on a PDF to Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, parsing, pdf

Very new to python. I've used the following code:

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

fp = open('Card.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lobj in layout:
        if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
            x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
            print('At %r is text: %s' % ((x, y), text))
```

Output looks like:

At (245.76, 685.4898) is text: STATEMENT

At (99.36, 538.7497999999999) is text: Type

At (210.0, 538.7497999999999) is text: Details

At (310.8, 538.7497999999999) is text: Reference

I want to put specific text into columns in a CSV e.g. Any text at (99.36, 538.7497999999999) to go in column 1, etc

How would I go about this?

Comment: what data you need to collect in witch columns in excel?

Comment: Say data from (245.76, 685.4898) in column 1, (99.36, 538.7497999999999) in column 2, etc

Comment: you need to collect `x,y,text` in separate columns?

Comment: Yep exactly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Zaraki, I get the follow error: x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
AttributeError: 'LTCurve' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: it means that you variable `lobj` is not a object on witch you can call attribute  `get_text()`. What data type is `lobj`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this task:

```
import pandas as pd

df_results = pd.DataFrame()
for lobj in layout:
    x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
    collected_data = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'text': text}
    data = pd.Series(collected_data)
    df_results = df_results.append(data, ignore_index=True)

df_results.to_csv('coordinates_data.csv')
```

It will collect data into data frame and then save as csv.